# What is the correct way of using Metamask SDK with type script

Tags: typescript, metamask

I am trying to create a webpack+pnpm+typescript+react browser site.
All versions are LTS and my IDE is VSCode.
The Metamask's guide [says](https://docs.metamask.io/wallet/how-to/use-sdk/javascript/react/) that I need to do something like this:

```
npm i @metamask/sdk
```

and then just use it

```
import { MetaMaskSDK } from '@metamask/sdk';
const MMSDK = new MetaMaskSDK(options);
const ethereum = MMSDK.getProvider();
```

But one I tried to import the SDK with "*import { MetaMaskSDK } from '@metamask/sdk'*" I got not type hinting and a warning:

> Could not find a declaration file for module '@metamask/sdk'.
> 'project/node_modules/.pnpm/@metamask+sdk@0.3.3_@types+react@18.2.14_react-native@0.71.11_react@18.2.0/node_modules/@metamask/sdk/dist/node/cjs/metamask-sdk.js'
> implicitly has an 'any' type.   Try `npm i --save-dev @types/metamask__sdk` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts)
> file containing `declare module '@metamask/sdk';`ts(7016)

The thing is that I as much as I know, there are really no any module declarations in the SDK's module folder. There are some subfolders there like "browser/es" etc. 
What is the correct way to import the Metamask SDK into a web-application?

Comment: Ok. I see that metamsk SDK has "types: dist/browser/es/src/index.d.ts" in package.json  while the real types path is "dist/browser/es/sdk/index.d.ts". No idea how could they achieve that and why no one cares, but probably that's the reason/

Answer (score 1):

Ok the thing is that, for some reason SDK's creators have broken the building environment. As result, the modules' package.json file contains a wrong path to the typing file.
There is

> "types": "dist/browser/es/src/index.d.ts",

while it must have been

> "types": "dist/browser/es/**sdk**/src/index.d.ts",

I tried to fill [a bug report](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-sdk/issues/172) regarding this and the guys promised to fix the bug.
The issue can be temporary and dirty fixed but fixed the "types" value of the installed module (right in the "node_modules/@metamsk/sdk/package.json" file). But it will be reverted back to the wrongvalue every time you update the package, and you must to in every created building environment.
I use pnpm package manager so I can fix on only once for all my projects.

I am going to the questions and this answer to let other people know that they are doing everything right, but there is a bug in the package. There is no any mention of this problem over Internet, and I spent some time trying to figure things out.
If you think I need to remove the question, just let me know.